# Rearrange a grouping of numbers into a list of tuples

Tags: python

Given:

```
x = '1 (2,3), 4 (5)'
```

How would I get:

```
y = [(1,2),(1,3),(4,5)] ?
```

Thank you.

Comment: do you mean: `x` is a string and you want to "distribute" values `1` and `4` to every value within the brackets?

Comment: Felix Kling: I was using a re to get what is within the parentheses and then using .split() on comma separated values, but haven't been able to quite work it out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> x = '1 (2,3), 4 (5)'
>>> gp = re.compile('\d+\s*\([\d,]+\)(?=,?)')
>>> # digit, whitespace, (, digits or commas, ), maybe a comma
>>> for token in gp.findall(x):
...     token = token.split("(", 1)
...     left, right = int(token[0]), map(int, token[1][:-1].split(","))
...     for elt in right:
...             print((left, elt))
...
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(4, 5)
```

Warning: this is fragile because of the regex-based parsing. (For instance, it assumes all your numbers are integers.) If your input is more flexible than I have assumed, you may wish to consider either generalising the regex or moving to a proper parsing library.

A neat use would be to put it in a function and change `print` to `yield`, to make it a generator.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this helps or not but it works for me:

```
x = '1 (2,3,9), 4 (5), 7'

output = []

for y in x.split(')'):
    if not y:
        continue
    data = y.split('(')
    right = int(data[0].strip(' ,'))
    if len(data) == 2:
        output.extend([(right, int(c)) for c in data[1].split(',')])
    else:
        output.append((right, ))

print output
>>> [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 9), (4, 5), (7,)]
```